# Game doesn't load on itch.io

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm on Unity 2020.1.14 and I can't get my WebGL Build to load on itch.io (stuck at 0%), but when I run it in my browser normally it works just fine.

I tried removing the compression, enabling compression rollback, and setting it in development build mode.

The steps for my build are:

1. Build
2. Zip the three files (index.html, Build, TemplateData) into one
3. Choose HTML as type of project on itch.io
4. Upload the zip (choose "Played on browser" option)
5. Save

Comment: Can you provide the logs you get in the browser while running the game on `itch.io`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed itself as I was copying the logs.
2 days that it didnt work mind you.